# javascript appendChild doesn't seem to be working for IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, append

I want to listed for clicks on link.php and after opening the new tab, appends a div to the old tab and fills it up by loading from a file. This works fine on firefox & chrome but doesn't seem to work on any version of IE. In those, the links work fine, but the div doesn't append:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {    
        var href = e.target.closest("a").href || "";
        if (href.indexOf("link.php") > -1) {

            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.setAttribute("id", "lightbox");
            div.setAttribute("style",   "width:100%;height:100%;background:#000;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;zIndex:50;MsFilter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60);filter:alpha(opacity=60);MozOpacity:0.6;KhtmlOpacity:0.6;opacity:0.6");
            document.body.appendChild(div);

            var divv = document.createElement("div");
            divv.setAttribute("id", "N_div");
            document.body.appendChild(divv);
            $( "#N_div" ).load( "/forms/div.php" );
            $("#N_div").fadeIn("fast");
        }
    }, false);
</script>
```

Using jquery 2.1.4 (although I tried it with 3.1.1 and it didn't work any better). Doctype is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

I made an honest attempt at debugging IE on a PC but honestly I'm so spoiled by mac OS at this point that I can barely operate a PC anymore. It's just a miserable experience and I figured this might be a common, easily solved problem. Does anything jump out to you as being disastrously wrong?

Comment: Ah, what's the best alternative?

Comment: Internet Explorer is incloded in browser compatibility as you could see in documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Comment: did you intend to remove the [tag:jquery] tag too? note too that you're fading in the form before it is loaded, so... not a whole lot of point for the animation there.

Comment: Already using `fadeIn` and `load` in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MDN ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest ) it does not look like IE has support yet for `closest` natively.  For the time being you could try using the jQuery method instead.

```
$(e.target).closest('a').attr('href') || ""
```

Comment: Ahh that's the stuff! I appreciate the help.